# How to numerically solve a Green's function using mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations

Suppose we have a Green's function
$$LG(x)=\delta(x),$$
how to numerically solve it by mathematica? Can the mathematica read the delta function directly?
For analytical calculation, we usually decompose $G(x)$ as $G(x)=\theta(x)G^>(x)+\theta(-x) G^<(x)$, and we have
$$LG^>(x)=0,\\
LG^<(x)=0.$$
If the general solotion to $LG(x)=0$ is $c_1y_1+c_2y_2$, then we can assume
$$G^<(x)=A_1y_1(x)+A_2y_2(x),x<0\\
G^>(x)=B_1y_1(x)+B_2y_2(x),x<0.$$ 
The coefficients can be determined by consistency condition (the continuous condition and the Wronskian...) and boundary (initial) conditions.
However, in general we can not obtain the solutions to $LG=0$ and can not define the Wronskian, then how can we solve the Green's function numerically.

Comment: "Numerically solve it"? What do you mean by that?

Comment: @WeinEld But look up the Mathematica symbol `GreenFunction`.

Comment: @WillieWong Thank you very much for your remind.

Comment: @PatrickStevens, Ok, I will check it, really thank you very much!